# How to set memcached options in Yii2?

Tags: php, memcached, yii2

I'm trying to set a Memcached option (disable compression) in the config file, but Yii2 keeps throwing an error.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the config:

```
'cache' => [
    /* 'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache', */
    'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
    'servers' => [
        [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 11211,
        ],
    ],
    'useMemcached' => true,
    'serializer' => false,
    'options' => [
        'Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION' => false,
    ],
],
```

And the error:
*'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Memcached::setOptions(): invalid configuration option'*

Any ideas?

If I do the same thing in plain PHP, it works just fine:

```
$memcache = new \Memcached;
$memcache->setOption(\Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION, false);
$memcache->addServers(
    array(
        array("HOST" => "127.0.0.1", "PORT" => 11211),
    )
);
```

Comment: I have tested your configuration. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
'options' => [
    \Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION => false,
],
```